# Server Error in '/' Application on web site Hosting on internet issue C# aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I have a Website that is hosted on WWW/internet, when I tried to open abcxxx.com/WebApplicationASP/login/login.aspx its showing below error;

```
Server Error in '/' Application 
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Login.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplicationASP.Login.Login" %>
```

Same Web site hosted on my local PC in IIS showing no errors. Its working fine.

I have googled and found I need to change CodeBehind to CodeFile:
now I got the below Error:

```
Parser Error Message: The file '/WebApplicationASP/login/Login.aspx.cs' does not exist.
```

Is that means I have to add C# source files too ?

I published website in my localPC using IIS at filesystem  C:\inetpub\wwwroot\WebApplicationASP  same file structure I have put on my www hosting site? Do I need to do anything more to make it work ?

Thanks,
Ashok

Comment: Have you checked to see that file exists in that path on the web server?

Comment: are you building your web app?

Comment: yes, I'm building my own Web App.  do I need to keep source files there?

Comment: In My Web applilcation I have sub directories Login , Home, Results is that causing a problem?